# sending data between controllers and persis after reloading angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

What is preferred way to share data (Object) between controllers with different routes and **prevent data lost after reloading**?
I need this object to prefill form values in my destination page which depends on choices in my source page.

Solutions I got so far are:
1- to send serialized Objects as query string parameter.
2- or using local storage and give special parameter to url so it knows when to fetch from local storage and when to open empty form.

Solutions which I can't use:
1- Shared service as my data would be lost after reload in this case.

Is there any other way, if not which way is more preferred?
**note:** there has to be no lost data after reloading page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: @ruby_newbie, My question is different as it has to meet the condition of not losing data after reloading page.    
this case is not common as it is SPA, but I need a solution for this case.

Comment: If you need it after reloading the page your only choices are to store it in a session on the server, a cookie, or localStorage. After that it's just a matter of pulling the data out of one of those places on reload and "hydrating" your app with it.

Comment: @BaselIssmail did my answer worked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO , there could be only 2 ways to handle this:

1. Using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`
2. You use `session` management from server side keep the session consistent.

If it's just about retaining the data after page reload for a route, just go for `sessionStorage`. But it depends on the use case of your project.